# Can't set delegate in SWRevealViewController on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController on storyboard. I implemented prepareForSegue method but I don't know how to set delegate of any view controller so I can implement some methods

**revealControllerPanGestureBegan** and
**revealControllerPanGestureEnded**

I tried the following code :

**SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];**

**[revealController setDelegate:self];**

but it doesn't work. Anybody has any idea?

- I am using SWRevealViewController with storyboard. Is there any way to set delegate by storyboard ? ( I mean by inspector window ) ?
- If it doesn't work with storyboard then can you tell me how to implement by code ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about SWRevealViewController but in general it is done like this with storyboard:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueId"]) {
       SWRevealViewController *rvController = (SWRevealViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
       rvController.delegate = self;
       // set other properties..
    }
}
```